# Why is my neural net getting a poor accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, cnn

```
EPOCH=40
batch_size=50
mnist=input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)

tf.reset_default_graph()

input_X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[None, 10])

input_layer=tf.layers.dense(input_X, 784, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
hidden1=tf.layers.dense(input_layer, 256, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
hidden2=tf.layers.dense(hidden1, 256, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
output=tf.layers.dense(hidden2, units=10)
output=tf.nn.softmax(output)


entropy=tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=input_y, logits=output)
loss=tf.reduce_mean(entropy)
step=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

#correct=tf.nn.in_top_k(tf.argmax(output, y, 1) rank error

correct=tf.equal(tf.argmax(output, 1), tf.argmax(input_y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))


sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for epoch in range(EPOCH):
  for i in range(1000):
    X, y=mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
    sess.run(loss, feed_dict={input_X:X, input_y:y})
  acc_train=accuracy.eval(feed_dict={input_X:X, input_y:y})
  acc_val=accuracy.eval(feed_dict={input_X: mnist.validation.images
                                  , input_y: mnist.validation.labels})
  print(epoch, "Train accuracy: ", acc_train, "\n Val accuracy: ", acc_val)
```

Results went something like this-

```
0 Train accuracy:  0.1 
 Val accuracy:  0.0986
1 Train accuracy:  0.14 
 Val accuracy:  0.0986
2 Train accuracy:  0.06 
 Val accuracy:  0.0986
3 Train accuracy:  0.06 
 Val accuracy:  0.0986
```

I have referenced part of the code from `O'Reily` textbook on `Tensorflow`.

EDIT- found this O' Reily guide online-https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/10_introduction_to_artificial_neural_networks.ipynb

They have a code similar to mine but their's works just fine.

Comment: You have to train it much more than this.

Comment: I just posted the first few lines but my val accuracy stays the same throughout and my train accuracy never goes above 11%. I have also tried increasing the range but it only pushed the result to 10.5%.

Comment: Just change activation to relu and see the magic.

Comment: add comments to your code. it helps people to sooner understand your code and help you.

Comment: @DuttaA It went up to 14% but that's it. This is depressing.

Comment: Check the input data. Is it scaled 0..255, or scaled 0..1?

Comment: Did you follow Neil's advice?...Also why are you doing 2 times softmax?

Comment: Can we get access to your data please?

Comment: @NeilSlater I was bit confused about scaling. My single layer perceptron ended up performing worse after I scaled the data but I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @JahKnows It's the mnist data. mnist=input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True), this line gets the data.

Comment: @NeilSlater it dropped to 7.74% :(

Answer (score 4):

Reason is you did not train the network.

You need to run the `step` op in your code. You defined it, but didn't use it anywhere later. Running the  `loss` only calculates the loss, but does not train your network.

**after fixing your code** (remove duplicate softmax, using adadelta, run `step`) you should get:
[image]

Comment: I thought this was it but for some reason even this isn't working. Nice catch though.

Comment: If you fixed that, you should be able to get >90% accuracy on both training and validation within 10 epochs, using <code>step=tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)</code>.

Comment: I got 87%. Why did the performance improve with AdadeltaOptimizer? I am glad that it did but the O' Reily code gets 97% using code similar to mine( including using GradientDescentOptimizer). Great suggestion though.

Comment: The OReily code use relu for activation instead of sigmoid. If you do that you can also get >97% within 10 epochs.

Answer (score 2):

I have two suggestions.

1. Change your optimiser to `AdamOptimizer`.
2. Change the number of neurons in the hidden layers. They are too many for this task. Two layers with 25 neurons for each layer will suffice.

   ---

   Omit `output=tf.nn.softmax(output)`. Due to calculating that in the `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. As you can read in the document of the function `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`:

> **WARNING:** This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a `softmax`
>   on `logits` internally for efficiency.  Do not call this op with the
>   output of `softmax`, as it will produce incorrect results.

Comment: Tried that. Didn't help much.

Comment: What is your accuracy now?

Comment: It is almost 15% now

Comment: And how many epoch or iteration does it take? Also take a look at the update.